# How do I enforce that certain characters must be present when there is an optional character before them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to capture a string that meets the criteria:

1. may be empty
2. if it is not empty it must have up to three digits (-> `\d{1,3}`)
3. may be optionally followed by a uppercase letter (`[A-Z]?`)
4. may be optionally followed by a forward slash (i.e. `/`) (-> `\/?`); if it is followed by a forward slash it must have from one to three digits
   (-> `\d{1,3}`)

Here's a valid input:

- 35
- 35A
- 35A/44

Here's invalid input:

- 34/ (note the lack of a digit after '/')

I've come up with the following [^\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,1}/?[1,3]?$](https://regex101.com/r/KX12um/4) that satisfies conditions 1-3. How do I deal with 4 condition? My Regex fails at two occassions:

- fails to match when there is a digit and a forward slash and a digit e.g .`77A/7`
- matches but it shouldn't when there isa digit and a forward slash, e.g. `77/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}[A-Z]?(?:\/\d{1,3})?)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUIgHH/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{1,3}[A-Z]?(?:\/\d{1,3})?)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
  - `[A-Z]?` - an optional uppercase ASCII letter
  - `(?:\/\d{1,3})?` - an optional non-capturing group:

    - `\/` - a `/` char
    - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Visual graph (generated [here](https://jex.im/regulex)):

[image]

Comment: It does the trick. Would you be kind enought to discuss your solution in more details?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You were matching an optional slash and then an optional digit from 1 to 3; this matches an optional combination of a slash and 1-3 of any digits. Also, your original regex could match 0 digits at the beginning; I believe that this was in error, so I fixed that.

```js
var regex = /^(\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,1}(\/\d{1,3})?)?$/g;

console.log("77A/7 - "+!!("77A/7").match(regex));
console.log("77/ - "+!!("77/").match(regex));
console.log("35 - "+!!("35").match(regex));
console.log("35A - "+!!("35A").match(regex));
console.log("35A/44 - "+!!("35A/44").match(regex));
console.log("35/44 - "+!!("35/44").match(regex));
console.log("34/ - "+!!("34/").match(regex));
console.log("A/3 - "+!!("A/3").match(regex));
console.log("[No string] - "+!!("").match(regex));
```